# How thick/thin dielectric material would change electric field in reactive near field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, dielectric, antennas

What would happen to an antenna, tested with magnetic probes in the reactive near field, when the distance between probes and antenna was filled in by:

**1)** *Thin Air* and *Thick Dielectric* (Probes - 1mm Air - 1 cm Dielectric - Antenna)

**2)** *Thick Air* and *Thin Dielectric* (Probes - 1cm Air - 1 mm Dielectric - Antenna)

How does reducing the dielectric thickness affect the capacitance and the strength of the electric field?